# Iframe is giving blank page

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I am using iframe in jsp page.

```
<iframe frameborder="1" src="view/jsp/refreshChat.jsp" STYLE='width:20%;' />
```

But when I run that page its gives a blank page.

Comment: add some more information that can help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of an iframe code:

```
<iframe src="page_to_show_inside_iframe.jsp" style="width:100%; height:250px;">
  <p>Text to show in browsers that don't support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Perhaps you're lacking **height** value.

Also, be sure the value for **src** attribute is correctly referenced, ie. relative path is built OK ( if your parent page URL is `http://localhost:8080/mysite/`**`myparentpage.jsp`**  try to load your child page pasting src value instead your parent page's name, `http://localhost:8080/mysite/`**`view/jsp/refreshChat.jsp`** , test this in a new window or tab)

Comment: the folder location of my parent and child page are same,
i have tried with height value 2 but same problem persists

Comment: if the folder location of your parent and child page are the same (they are at same depth) then remove `view/jsp/` part on **src**.

Answer (score 0):

Check if src="view/jsp/refreshChat.jsp" is proper. From what location You use this?

Comment: ya i checked 3ice that this loc is fine

Answer (score 0):

DO not forget to add http:// to your web url. Also, avoid localhost. Use the IP address.